# array out of bound with inappropriate output

Tags: android

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment


        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1, container, false);

        recyclerView =  view.findViewById(R.id.recyler);
        adapter = new tabAdapter(getActivity(),getdata());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        return view;
    }

    public List<information> getdata(){

        List<information> data = new ArrayList<>();
        int[] im = {R.mipmap.ic_launcher,R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round,R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round,R.mipmap.ic_launcher};
        String[] ti ={"shubham","prasad","xxxxx","dummydata"};
        for(int i=0;i<ti.length && i<im.length;i++){
            information info = new information();
            info.img=im[i];
            info.str=ti[i];
            data.add(info);

        }
        return data;
    }
```

and getting exception
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.example.android.abc, PID: 3385
                                                                       java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4
                                                                           at com.example.android.abc.tab1.getdata(tab1.java:104)
                                                                           at com.example.android.abc.tab1.onCreateView(tab1.java:88)

tabAdapter class
public class tabAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private LayoutInflater lf;


List<information> data = Collections.emptyList();
```

public tabAdapter(Context context,List data){

```
   lf=LayoutInflater.from(context);
   this.data=data;
```

}

```
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = lf.inflate(R.layout.res,parent,false);

    MyViewHolder ms = new MyViewHolder(view);
    return ms;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    information info=data.get(position);

    holder.tx.setText(info.str);
    holder.tm.setImageResource(info.img);


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}


class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView tx;
    ImageView tm;
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tx = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ids);
        tm = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imag);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you have to do like below

```
for(int i=0;i<ti.length;i++){

    information info = new information();
    info.setImage(im[i]);
    info.setString(ti[i]);
    data.add(info);

    }
```

updated answer.

in your `bindview` of your `adapter` you have to write like below

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    information info=data.get(position);

    holder.tx.setText(info.getString());
    holder.tm.setImageResource(info.getImage());
}
```

your information class like below

```
public class information implements Serializable {
    private  int img;
    private String str;

    public int getImg() {
        return img;
    }

    public void setImg(int img) {
        this.img = img;
    }

    public String getStr() {
        return str;
    }

    public void setStr(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }
}
```

Comment: error is resolved but it is just showing one data

Comment: have you solve the problem?

Comment: i dont have getString and getImage method in my class 
public class information {


    int img;
    String str;}

Comment: can you please share your information class

Comment: public class information {


    int img;
    String str;




}

Comment: still not working

Comment: found this in log E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Comment: you have to set `recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));` before setAdapter

Comment: yeah did that change but still having only one list displayed